# Is the loss is the same as the error in deep learning?

Tags: error, loss-functions, measurement-error

Is the **loss** is the same as the **error** in deep learning?

I feel it's the same but I'm maybe wong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually loss and error are different concepts, but sometimes people conflate the two because conceptually, they're similar.

Loss functions measure the misfit of the model -- how much the model is wrong.

Error usually is shorthand for "error rate," the proportion of samples misclassified.

These two concepts are not necessarily the same. For example, cross-entropy loss can be any non-negative number, but the error rate is some number between 0 and 1.

Moreover, the error rate is not a differentiable function so it is not suitable for use in the back-propagation algorithm. But cross-entropy loss *is* differentiable, and is perfectly reasonable to use in back-prop.

Comment: To see if I under-fit or over-fit my data should I look at the total loss or about the error rate? error rate = nbSamplesMisclassified/ nbSample right?

Comment: General questions about neural networks and overfitting have a number of threads on this website. Here's one that seems like a good place to start. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131233/neural-network-over-fitting You can find more using the search feature.